# Large batch logos and text over template

Tags: text, batch-processing, template

I'm trying to create materials to encourage the use of a service my company provides in order to register to vote. The way we are doing it now, is getting a county to sign up and then I create a promotional piece or two for every high school in that county. I've only done 1 county so far - and it was about 10 hours worth of work... I have other responsibilities and would love it if I could automate the task somehow so I have more time for other things. Here is the idea:

I take a template like this one 
[image: template]

and add the school logo in the top corner, along with the name at the top, in the phone, and below in red like this:

[image: Richmond High]

Obviously, this takes a matter of 15 minutes or so per picture, but when you have 2 different templates that need to be filled out it becomes quite tedious. (I am using paint.net so far but am open to buying new software if it solves this problem)

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Is this for web or print?

Comment: If it's for print, I'd use [Indesign and its "Data Merge"](https://youtu.be/768AlpLsEs4)... Although it's not the only application that does something like this and probably not the cheapest.

Comment: if you already solved this (by now I hope you did) you should write an answer and mark it as accepted, or accept whichever helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like you're looking for [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

If you know the steps to create your picture, you can use the [command line support](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) to create whatever image you like, including text, shapes, images, ...